# Negative of a Number in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops

I have to make a function in MATLAB in which when input will be given, output will be the negative of that number. 
The code that I wrote :

```
function [p] = negative(q)
% given an input , output will be negative of that input

w = subtract(0,1) ; 
[p] = multiply(q,w) ;
end
```

The code that I wrote for function subtract is :

```
function [m] = subtract(n,s)
m = n ;
while s
[m]= decrement(m) ;
s = decrement(s) ;
end
end
```

Code for multiply is :

```
function [a] = multiply(x,y)
a = x ;
y = decrement(y) ;
while y
[a]= addition(a,x);
y = decrement(y);
end
end
```

Function for addition :

```
 function [a] = addition(b,c)
 % adds b and c 
 a = b ;
 while c
 [a] = increment(a) ; 
  c = decrement(c) ;
 end
 end
```

Funtion increment code :

```
 function out = increment(in)
 out = in + 1;
 end
```

Function decrement is following :

```
function out = decrement(in)
 out = in - 1;
end
```

The code which I wrote for function negative should work according to me because I am multiplying the input with -1. But in MATLAB command window nothing is printed out (except w= -1) when I write negative(input) . Why is this and how shall I fix it ? 
I am NOT allowed to use any operation including ( + , - , * , / , < , > , ==) and neither am I allowed to use for loops. 
Only thing I can use is assignment ( = ) and while loop.

Comment: That's an awfully complicated way of changing `a` to `-a`.  Have your functions `multiply`, `addition`, `increment` and `decrement` passed all the tests you wrote, and were the tests comprehensive ?

Comment: You use - and + in the increment and decrement functions...

Comment: Other parts of the question were writing functions of addition, subtraction and multiplication. And yes all were correct on testing.

Comment: increment and decrement were the functions already given thats why they have + and -ve. the 4 functions I wrote those can't have operation signs

Comment: what about `||` and `&&`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I don't understand why you're writing 50 lines of code for a one line problem.
`out = -1 .* input;`

However, your problem lies here:

```
function [a] = multiply(x,y)
a = x ;
y = decrement(y) ; % --------------!!!
while y
[a]= addition(a,x);
y = decrement(y);  % --------------!!!
end
end
```

When y is negative, the loop keeps decrementing it and therefore, it never gets out of the loop.

y will be negative whenever you input a positive number Q in negative(Q).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you have some problems with `addition`,`subtract` and `multiply`, so I tried to avoid them.

Try this one,

```
function [p] = negative(q)
a = q;
b = q;
a = increment(a);
b = decrement(b);
while b && a
    a = decrement(a);
    b = increment(b);
end
while a
    q = increment(q);
    a = increment(a);
end
while b
    q = decrement(q);
    b = decrement(b);
end
p = q;
end
```

The idea is to define two variables, `a,b` same as `q` then increase one while decreasing the other,

so after the first loop, one of `a` or `b` will be `0` and the other will be `2xq`(no endless loop!).

Then we could easily use another loop to get `-q`, since we have `2xq`.

It seems to work well.

Comment: @Manahil, Didn't it work for you? it seems to do what you've asked.